# Quick way to set elments of a 2D vector that is a member of class into zero

Tags: c++, vector

is there any quick way to make all elements of a 2D vector zero? I have the following:

```
`typedef class Chrom             
{
    vector<vector <short int>> bit;
    vector<vector <float>> t1; //this is wij in the model
 }
chrome ProblemConstraint;
```

And after resizing I make t1 as t1[Machines][Jobs]. I wonder is there any quick way that I set all elements of t1 to zero? I know there is fill but when I write

```
    fill(ProblemConstraint.t1[0], ProblemConstraint.t1[0]+Jobs*Machines, 0);
```

I get error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `std::fill` takes iterators as parameters, so the call should be `fill(ProblemConstraint.t1[0].begin(), ProblemConstraint.t1[0].end(), 0);`

Comment: Most likely a vector of vector is a bad idea. If you want a matrix use a vector of size n*m. Wrap it in a class with `operator()(int row, int col)` or find an existing one.

Comment: `typedef class`? That’s used in C, but with struct. You don’t need that in C++.

Comment: @UnholySheep When I try this, I get the error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C3867 'std::vector<short,std::allocator<_Ty>>::begin': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: Did you forget the `()` at the end of the `begin`/`end`?

Comment: @manni66 It is relatively the only thing I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @UnholySheep commented, `std::fill` accepts the pair of the iterators you need to pass, not the pointer to the elements:

```
std::fill(ProblemConstraint.t1[0].begin(), ProblemConstraint.t1[0].end(), 0);
```

However, you can also initialize the values during resizing the vectors, as `std::vector::resize` has an overload with the element's default value:

```
void resize( size_type count, const value_type& value );
```

So, you could do:

```
t1[0].resize(Jobs, 0);
```

at the resize point.

Comment: Thanks, it works, what about when our class is array so for example if we have an array of problem constraints with the size of 10?

Comment: You can still use `std::fill` and you can use non-member `begin` and `end` (which will work both for vector and array): `std::fill(std::begin(ProblemConstraint.t1[0]), std::end(ProblemConstraint.t1[0]), 0);` (You need to include `iterator` for this).